# Add matrix to structure column without using for loop?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Is it possible to add a matrix to a structure 'column' without using a for-loop? For example I have a structure with 3 fields

```
A.name
A.grade
A.attendance
```

now `A.attendance` expects a 1x5 matrix. If I have a 5x5 matrix, can I directly insert it into 5 rows of the structure A? something like

```
A(1:5).attendance = B
```

where B is a 5x5 matrix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your `B` is actually a 5 element cell array where each element is a *1*-by-*5* matrix (actually each element can contain anything), then

```
[A.attendance] = B{:}
```

will work. You can convert your *5*-by-*5* double matrix `B` to the desired form as follows:

```
B_cell = mat2cell(B, ones(size(B,1),1),size(B,2))
```

or skip the temp variable and use `deal`:

```
[A.attendance] = deal(mat2cell(B, ones(size(B,1),1),size(B,1)))
```

Comment: So you can use `deal` directly on the cell without `{:}`. These things always confuse me!

Comment: @Luis I guess this is just what you said: `{:}` is itself an implicit `deal`. Using explicitly `deal` allows you to use a full cell, `deal` will deal with it for you.

Comment: @Andras I see it this way: `deal` allows you to use a "manually" defined comma-separated list on the RHS: `[A(1:5).attendance] = deal(1,3,5,7,9);`. That doesn't work without `deal`. But if that `1,3,5,7,9` list is _automatically_ generated from a cell array `C = {1,3,5,7,9}` as `C{:}`, then `deal` is not necessary from Matlab 7.0 onwards, even though `C{:}` produces precisely `1,3,5,7,9`

Comment: Here's Loren Shure on the subject: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/01/24/deal-or-no-deal/

Comment: Just to confirm explicitly, I can't store a double matrix as a double matrix directly (as mentioned above in the question) in a structure?

Comment: @user3079474 I'm not sure I understand what you mean. But you could change your struct to use the newish table data type maybe? You can't store names ina double matrix and less the names are all numeric.

Answer (score 6):

You can convert `B` to a cell array of its rows,

```
C = mat2cell(B, ones(size(B,1),1), size(B,2))
```

and then you can assign as follows

```
[A(1:size(B,2)).attendance] = C{:};
```

Comment: I was just thinking about a solution with `deal`:)

Comment: damn, I shouldn't have typed for as long ;) I don't think you need the index on `A`, `[A.attendance]` should work too

Comment: @Andras Actually there's an "implicit" `deal` on the right-hand side. It used to be necessary, but it's not anymore [since version 7.0](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html)

Comment: @LuisMendo sure, I realized *a posteriori*. But it was all too late;)

Comment: @Dan That's a good idea, but only if `A` is previously undefined or sufficiently small. If `A` has more than `size(B,1)` entries it will give an error